# example using rhino's JavaAdapter

Tags: java, scripting, rhino, adapter

Can someone provide me an example on how to extend a java class in java script using Rhino's java adapter ?

Comment: Java != JavaScript.  Never has been, never will be.

Comment: @A. Scagnelli: True, but Rhino allows you to script java. http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/

Comment: Look at this page: http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/ScriptingJava.html

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else who might come across this, there's a decent example [here](http://my.opera.com/sutabi/blog/putting-the-java-into-javascript-with-rhino) (the author uses it to extend `awt.Canvas`).

```
var smileyCanvas = new JavaAdapter(awt.Canvas, {
   paint: function (g) {
       var size = this.getSize();
       var d = Math.min(size.width, size.height);
       var ed = d / 20;
       var x = (size.width - d) / 2;
       var y = (size.height - d) / 2;
       // draw head (color already set to foreground)
       g.fillOval(x, y, d, d);
       g.setColor(awt.Color.black);
       g.drawOval(x, y, d, d);
       // draw eyes
       g.fillOval(x+d/3-(ed/2), y+d/3-(ed/2), ed, ed);
       g.fillOval(x+(2*(d/3))-(ed/2), y+d/3-(ed/2), ed, ed);
       //draw mouth
       g.drawArc(x+d/4, y+2*(d/5), d/2, d/3, 0, -180);
   }
});
```

There's [more information on MDN](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/scriptjava.html#javaadapter), including a brief explanation and calling syntax example.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on *what* you want to inherit. I find that if I use the JavaScript prototype for object “definitions” I get the static methods of Java objects only:

```
function test() {
  this.hello = function() {
    for(var i in this) {
      println(i);
    }
  };
}
test.prototype= com.acme.app.TestClass; // use your class with static methods
// see the inheritance in action:
var testInstance=new test();
test.hello();
```

However, JavaScript allows you to do prototype assignments on object instances as well, so you could use a function like this, and get a more Java-like inheritance behaviour:

```
function test(baseInstance) {
  var obj = new function() {
    this.hello=function() { 
      for(var i in this) { 
        println(i); 
      }
    };
  };
  obj.prototype=baseInstance; // inherit from baseInstance.
}

// see the thing in action:
var testInstance=test(new com.acme.TestClass()); // provide your base type
testInstance.hello();
```

Or use a function (e.g. `init`) similar to the above function in the object itself:

```
function test() {
  this.init=function(baseInstance) {
    this.prototype=baseInstance;
  };
  this.hello=function() {
    for(var i in this) {
      println(i);
    }
  };
}

var testInstance=new test();
println(typeof(testInstance.prototype)); // is null or undefined
testInstance.init(new com.acme.TestClass()); //  inherit from base object

// see it in action:
println(typeof(testInstance.prototype)); // is now com.acme.TestClass
testInstance.hello();
```

Comment: this is unrelated to the question. he's talking about rhino's JavaAdapter

Answer (score 2):

Since I am not a 100% sure that by Java Adapter you mean what I think it is, Java interfaces and such can be created with property lists (name = function()):

```
var runnable = new java.lang.Runnable({
   run: function() { println('hello world!'); } // uses methodName: implementationFunction convention
};
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable); // test it
```

Or alternatively for single-method things like that:

```
function runnableFunc() { println('hello world!'); }
var runnable = new java.lang.Runnable(runnableFunc); // use function name
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable); // test it
```

Comment: How can you extend another class like this? Wouldn't you need `JavaAdapter`?

Comment: With `prototype`, for an example please see my other answer.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, that doesn't actually extend the class; it doesn't create a Java class that inherits from another class as JavaAdapter does. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

E.g. starting a thread in Rhino:

```
function startThread(funcOfThread) {
    var someClass = { run: funcOfThread }; // Rhino syntax for new class with overwritten method
    var r = new java.lang.Runnable(someClass);
    var t = new java.lang.Thread(r);
    t.start();
}

function UDP_Client() {
    while (1)
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(100);
}

startThread(UDP_Client);
```